# RegularExpression Validation attribute not working correctly

Tags: c#, regex, validation, asp.net-core

I want to validate a property in my viewmodel to match a regular expression.

**Viewmodel:**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ProjectName.ViewModels
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "error message.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[a-zA-Z0-9][/\\]$/img", ErrorMessage = "End with '/' or '\\' character.")]
        public string FilePath { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model ProjectName.ViewModels.ViewModel
<form asp-action="EditPath" asp-controller="Files" id="EditFilePathForm">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label asp-for="FilePath" class="control-label"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input asp-for="FilePath" class="form-control"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="FilePath" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p>@Model.FileName</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
        <hr />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="cancelEditFilePathModal" data-dismiss="modal">Annuleren</button>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="Submit" value="Opslaan"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

The regular expression should check if the FilePath ends with a alphanumeric character followed by `/` or `\`.

[Link to Regex on Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/dX3hD4/121)

On Regex101.com this seems to work fine.
However when I test this in my application it seems to never match the expression and the error message keeps showing up.

What am I overlooking here?

Comment: Try `@".*[a-zA-Z0-9][/\\]$"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What's a difference ? he has no`^` at the beggining of regex, so no full match is required.

Comment: @tchelidze The whole difference is that the pattern is used in RegularExpressionAttribute. Well, if the validation is made on the server side, OP needs `@"(?i).*[a-zA-Z0-9][/\\]$"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So if I understand correctly the RegularExpressionAttribute forces you to use a regular expression which matches the whole string?

Comment: Yes. That is the main problem, not the typo with the flags.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know that. Microsoft isn't very clear on this in their documentation. Please make an answer to my question and I will accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`RegularExpressionAttribute`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/RegularExpressionAttribute.cs,57) requires the full sting match:

> `// We are looking for an exact match, not just a search hit. This matches what`
>      `// the RegularExpressionValidator control does`
>      `return (m.Success && m.Index == 0 && m.Length == stringValue.Length);`

So, you need to remove the flags (that is a typo) and use `^.*` before your pattern:

```
@"^.*[a-zA-Z0-9][/\\]$"
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I'm still able to set a string value with illegal characters in

Comment: @ataraxia That just means you have different requirements, other than what OP has.

Comment: I don't know how I can make a more basic test, I only allowed numbers, submitted letters, it just set it, regardless of which answer I went with here. I hate Regex.

Comment: @ataraxia Again, your issue is not the one in the current question. Either explain the pattern requirements, or ask a separate question. If you need to only allow a digit only string, it is `^[0-9]+$` or `^[0-9]*$`.

Answer (score 1):

On [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dX3hD4/121) `[a-zA-Z0-9][/\\]$` is used and in code `@"[a-zA-Z0-9][/\\]$/img"`

> [RegularExpression]: Validates that the data matches the specified regular expression

So you have to invert the regex

```
.*[^/\\]$
```

See [example](https://regex101.com/r/dX3hD4/123)

*Note*

In fact `[a-zA-Z0-9][/\\]$/img` is invalid regex, since `/` is not escaped in front of `img`