# asp-net: data-annotation regex DOESN'T WORK

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, validation, regex-lookarounds

### ASP-NET MVC PROJECT

[image]

I have tried to set a regular lookaround expression to a password field of a form. A simple example I tried is check that the user wrote a capital letter using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.

---

### Examples:

- [RegularExpression("**(?=.*[A-Z])**", ErrorMessage = "You have to write
  a capital letter")]

[image]

- [RegularExpression(**@"^(?=.*[A-Z])**", ErrorMessage = "You have to
  write a capital letter")]
  [image]

---

I prove this regular expression in this web page:http://regexstorm.net/tester
and I think this patron is correct.

In the login view I am using the directive asp-validation-for=@Model.password for checking the model is correct and if is not the server print the error message in the view and this is what always happens.

MICROSOFT GUIDE:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#lookarounds-at-a-glance

Answer (score 0):

You must provide a pattern that *consumes* the *entire* string when using regex with `RegularExpressionAttribute` (see [RegularExpression Validation attribute not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49557163/3832970)). Your `^(?=.*[A-Z])` regex pattern matches only the start of a string position because `^` is an anchor asserting the string start position and the `(?=.*[A-Z])` is a positive lookahead, a *non-consuming* pattern, that just returns "true" if there are zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then an ASCII uppercase letter.

You can use

```cs
[RegularExpression(@"^.*[A-Z].*", ErrorMessage = "You have to write a capital letter")]
```

Or, a more efficient

```cs
[RegularExpression(@"^[^A-Z]*[A-Z].*", ErrorMessage = "You have to write a capital letter")]
```

In case there can be line breaks in the input text, replace `.` with `[\w\W]`:

```cs
[RegularExpression(@"^[^A-Z]*[A-Z][\w\W]*", ErrorMessage = "You have to write a capital letter")]
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^A-Z]*` - zero or more chars other than ASCII uppercase letters
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase letter
- `[\w\W]*` - zero or more chars as many as possible.